# How to put data into Text view mode for android application. I am able to put it in Log but not able to put it in Text view mode

Tags: android

```
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListneronButton();

    }

    public void addListneronButton(){
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions=new StringBuffer();
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
                Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
                try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
                            appNameAndPermissions.append(packageInfo.packageName+"*:\n");
                //Get Permissions
                String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
                if(requestedPermissions != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
                appNameAndPermissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
                }
                appNameAndPermissions.append("\n");
                }
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.amazon.permissiondetector.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
android:background="@color/black">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/buttontext"
    android:width="150dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to android development so not have much idea.Creating app to detect permission used by all app in connected device. Like addon detector.I should display like App tile and below what permission used by the app.Guys help me !!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a TextView widget in your layout file. For example, you can add this below the button :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_permissions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Then set it's text property at the end of `addListneronButton()` as below :

```
txt_permissions.setText(appNameAndPermissions.toString())
```